# Wine crashes when trying to open an app through PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I've installed an app (Paint tool Sai) through PlayOnLinux. Each time I try to open it either it does absolutely nothing or a pop-up appears and writes this:

Error in POL_Wine
Wine seems to have crashed
If your program is running, just ignore this message

The app doesn't launch.
I've tried using Wine 3.10, 2.12 staging and 1.5.5-SAI.
I've also tried to reinstall the app multiple times with no effect.

I've looked in PlayOnLinux Debugger and got this:

`[06/20/18 18:10:01] - Running wine-2.12-staging /usr/share/playonlinux/python/lib (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
wine: cannot find L"Z:\\usr\\share\\playonlinux\\python\\lib."
[06/20/18 18:38:11] - Running wine-2.12-staging sai.exe (Working directory : /home/alika/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/PaintToolSai/drive_c/PaintToolSAI)
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 2.12 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"winebus.sys": libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
err:winedevice:async_create_driver failed to create driver L"WineBus": c0000142
err:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken Unhandled Token Information class 19!`

Is there any way to prevent Wine from crashing?

Thanks in advance.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't seem to work https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=4594
But try with the stable version of wine (version 3.0.1)